# Sending Frames Among Routers needs MACs?

Tags: arp, networking

Following this discussion:

[ARP request outside of LAN; Target machine or router response?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/arp-request-outside-of-lan-target-machine-or-router-response)

I'd like to understand if router 1 sends its frames to router 2 through the same ARP process as discussed for LAN. In a few words, does communication among routers need MACs (and ARP request possibly)in order to send their frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When routers are connected by Ethernet (or another MAC-based L2 protocol) they need to use ARP or NDP to resolve the next hop's IPv4 or IPv6 address - just like an end node.